# How to handle hundreds of identical databases with Django?

Tags: mysql, database, django

I have a legacy system that I'd like to extend with an application written in Django. The system hosts hundreds of small websites on the same server. A Mysql server takes care of the data: each website has its own Mysql database, (name derived from the hostname) with identical table structure. The list of all sites (hostnames and database names) is managed in a table in a separate database.

I don't need the Django user/session tables at all, or the Django admin module.

Is it possible to write Django code so that:

1. each Mysql query gets a correct database name (ultimately based on the request's `Host` header)
2. I don't have to hardcode the hostname list in eg. `settings.py`.  When a website is added or renamed, everything "just works" (or maybe I can send a signal to reload the site list).

Comment: This article explains how you can do it. It's well worth a read: http://blog.uysrc.com/2011/03/23/serving-multiple-sites-with-django/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django spports multi-db, that means, you can use more than one DB on a single project.

[Documentation is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/).

On the other hand, Your second need might not be possible in simple ways. Somehow, you must add a new DB description to `settings.py` file. There is one possible way o solve this, but it is not a good one in some ways...

When you define a new web site (from an UI interface like a webpage), you can write a script to open `settings.py` and add your new db information to DATABASE schema and save it and reload your settings... But as i said, writing `settings.py` programatically is dangerous.

Comment: Writing to `settings.py` from your application is not just dangerous, it's really hard to get right if you have multiple requests.  You'll need to have some sort of locking mechanism to prevent two concurrent requests from each overwriting part of the file at the same time.  Plus, you'll pay for that overhead on each request.  If you're going to go down that alley, a better way would probably to edit the `settings.py` file from a management command and run *that* once for each site.